# Pytesseract not recognizing numbers properly

Tags: python, sudoku, python-tesseract

The sudoku I'm trying to read

[image: The sudoku I'm trying to read]

I need to be able to read what's written on a given sudoku picture.
To do so, I use pytesseract to check every tile seperately cropped (This part works 200%).
Here is the part of the code I use :

```py
pytesseract.image_to_string(case, lang='eng', \
            config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

But when I print what has been read, I get this :

The values printed by the code

[image: The values printed by the code]

Even some other tries show that pytesseract seems to not recognize some numbers.
Ones and sevens, sometimes nines aren't being read, or even 1, 2, 5 and 8 being counted as ones...

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, it would be great !

Comment: Did you search for, perhaps, _optimise tesseract ocr_? https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html

Comment: what is the version of tesseract and pytesseract, as older versioned required white fonts on black background

Comment: you might wanna try other options -> [Inaccurate image2string pytesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62006776/12128167)

Comment: Starting image resolution is not great. And there is a lot of compression artifacts in the JPG image. A clean PNG image would be preferred if you can get it. Tesseract likes a minimum character height, so you'll probably have to scale the image (2x, 4x, even 8x) to get better results. To work on _this_ image, you'll have to threshold it somehow. And if you have difficulty recognizing certain numbers, you may have to resort to template matching from OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

I think you nearly solved the problem.

Most probably, if you remove the lines in the sudoku, you will succeed in recognizing digits.

For instance; you can use `fastLineDetector` and result will be:

[image]

Now if you apply `adaptive-threshold` threshold:

[image]

If you read now:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(txt)
```

Result:

```
2135976
7 6 1325

543 691
9426 87
63 17 42
178234596
8618 3 79
3 976215

27 15683
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("I1Kzk.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
lns = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector(_length_threshold=15).detect(gry)

if lns is not None:
    for ln in lns:
        (x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end) = ln[0]
        cv2.line(gry, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 255, 255), thickness=4)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 23)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 6 digits")
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Explanation**

- `createFastLineDetector` method is used to find the lines in the current image. If you set the line color with the same as the background, you make the lines disappear in the current image.
- `adaptive-threshold` and gray (`gry` variable) outputs look nearly the same. However, if you read from the gray output, you will have the wrong numbers.
- The output is not perfect, for instance:

  - `2135976` there should be a space between `7` and `6`.
  - It should be `213597  6` , but I'm focused on getting the correct number. Therefore the solution might help you solve the problem.